# Building wheels for upstream source dists

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel

Background:

My environment runs on a non-standard architecture, so when doing `pip install`, it often has to build wheels for dependencies from their sdists. I want to limit the amount of times this has to happen and speed up my builds, especially for dependencies with C extensions.

I do have access to a private PyPI index where I can upload sdists or wheels, so I was thinking I could have a weekly job running which pre-compiles the wheels of the more time consuming dependencies and upload these wheels to my private index.

Question:

Given the name of a dependency and version, what is the easiest way I can download the sdist for that dependency and build the wheel? e.g. I image something like:

```
wget $PIP_INDEX_URL/some/index/package_version.tar
tar xf package_version.tar
python -m build -w -o dist/ .
twine upload --repository private-pypi dist/*
```

Comment: `pip download --no-binary=:all: --no-deps package==version`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this use `pip wheel` combined with `pip download`, thanks to [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd). Its as simple as:

```
pip download --no-binary=:all: --no-deps ${PACKAGE}==${VERSION}
pip wheel --no-deps ${PACKAGE}-${VERSION}.tar.gz 
twine upload --repository private-pypi ./*
```